# find length between each point from array python

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

suppose we have 8 point whose x,y coordinates are given as

```
[[[224  64]]
 [[ 62 381]]
 [[224 661]]
 [[568 661]]
 [[733 348]]
 [[650 205]]
 [[509 204]]
 [[509  64]]]
```

Suppose these are 8 points of a polygon and want to find the length of each side. For two points, I am able to find the length as

```
dx = math.abs(x2 - x1)
dy = math.abs(y2 - y1)
dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

How to find length of each side of polygon with above `x, y` coordinates?

Comment: Um, you just repeat that computation 8 times, presumably in a loop.  And that's not an octagon.  It's 5 sides of a hexagon.

Comment: yes m facing difficulty in looping only @TimRoberts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
points = [
 [224,  64],
 [ 62, 381],
 [224, 661],
 [568, 661],
 [733, 348],
 [650, 205],
 [509, 204],
 [509,  64]]

for x,y in zip(points,points[1:]):
    d = math.sqrt((x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1]) + (x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0]))
    print(x, y, d)
```

Output:

```
[224, 64] [62, 381] 355.99578649191903
[62, 381] [224, 661] 323.4872485894923
[224, 661] [568, 661] 344.0
[568, 661] [733, 348] 353.82764165621654
[733, 348] [650, 205] 165.3420696616563
[650, 205] [509, 204] 141.00354605470034
[509, 204] [509, 64] 140.0
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

***FOLLOWUP***

Here's the code using your exact structure:

```
import numpy as np
import math
points = [
 [224,  64],
 [ 62, 381],
 [224, 661],
 [568, 661],
 [733, 348],
 [650, 205],
 [509, 204],
 [509,  64]]
points = np.array(points).reshape(8,1,2)
print(points)
for pt in zip(points,points[1:]):
    print( pt )
    x = pt[0][0]
    y = pt[1][0]
    d = math.sqrt((x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1]) + (x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0]))
    print(x, y, d)
```

Output:

```
[[[224  64]]
 [[ 62 381]]
 [[224 661]]
 [[568 661]]
 [[733 348]]
 [[650 205]]
 [[509 204]]
 [[509  64]]]
(array([[224,  64]]), array([[ 62, 381]]))
[224  64] [ 62 381] 355.99578649191903
(array([[ 62, 381]]), array([[224, 661]]))
[ 62 381] [224 661] 323.4872485894923
(array([[224, 661]]), array([[568, 661]]))
[224 661] [568 661] 344.0
(array([[568, 661]]), array([[733, 348]]))
[568 661] [733 348] 353.82764165621654
(array([[733, 348]]), array([[650, 205]]))
[733 348] [650 205] 165.3420696616563
(array([[650, 205]]), array([[509, 204]]))
[650 205] [509 204] 141.00354605470034
(array([[509, 204]]), array([[509,  64]]))
[509 204] [509  64] 140.0
```

Comment: hii thanks for detailed solution but i m facing problem while looping the array which i have shown in question, my program is returning array like that from where i have to calculate the length of side ..hat you have shown is on list .

Comment: i have tried to convert the array to list by array.tolist() but its giving error as IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What you have is am 8x1x2 array.  So, each element is a 1-element list that contains a 2-element point.  You'll need to handle that extra level.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: for x,y in zip(approx,approx[1:]):
#     print(x[0],y[0])
    d = math.sqrt((x[0][1]-y[0][1])*(x[0][1]-y[0][1]) + (x[0][0]-y[0][0])*(x[0][0]-y[0][0]))
    print('length between point:',x[0],'and', y[0],'is', d)
using this it was done thanks

Comment: my original image is closed one so in place of having 7 sides it should have get the length of all 8 sides any changes to make for that

Comment: The easy way is to wrap the first point around to the end: `for pt in zip(points,points[1:]+points[0:1]):`

Comment: above method is not working can u check from yr side

Comment: Ah, because the `+` is doing vector addition, not list concat.  I'm a little disappointed you couldn't look this up.  Use `for pt in zip(points,np.roll(points,-1,0)):`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your list is called `coords`. You have a `numpy` tag, so I am assuming you want a fast solution using numpy.

```
coords = [
 [224,  64],
 [ 62, 381],
 [224, 661],
 [568, 661],
 [733, 348],
 [650, 205],
 [509, 204],
 [509,  64]]
```

You will want to call `np.diff` on the successive elements, so to get the last side, you will want to replicate the first point at the end. You can do this as the same time as you convert your array to numpy:

```
vertices = np.concatenate((coords, coords[:1]), axis=0)
```

Now find the lengths of the sides:

```
sides = np.linalg.norm(np.diff(vertices, axis=0), axis=-1)
```

For your 2D case, you could also use `np.hypot` instead of `np.linalg.norm`:

```
sides = np.hypot(*np.diff(vertices, axis=0).T)
```